# Split String to DataGridview Loop

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
string csv = "John,Doe,21";
string[] split = csv.Split(',');

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn firstName = new 
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn lastName = new 
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn age = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(firstName);
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(lastName);
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(age);

dataGridView1.Rows.Add(split);
```

The code above was posted by @David Hall, my problem is that i can find a way to do the loop part.

Original post:
[C# : Split String and put it in the first column of a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774233/c-sharp-split-string-and-put-it-in-the-first-column-of-a-datagridview)

Comment: I think you meant to tag this C# rather than C.  I know nothing about C#, btw, but if you simply asking how to write a loop to iterate over split then please clarify question to say so.

Comment: Your current code creates a “single” line of text to split. I assume that instead you would want to “read” numerous “lines” of text that are in a file. If so, then, I suggest you look at the `StreamReader` Class and use it to “read” a CSV file. With each line read, you would “split” the line, and add the three (3) fields into a row in the grid.

Comment: You would use the `StreamReader` to open a file and read the file one line at a time until no more lines are in the file. With each line read, you would split the line into the three (3) strings and add those three strings to a new row in the grid. You could do this like… `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(split[0],split[1],split[2]);` Put the code that splits the line and adds the row to the grid inside a `while` loop that reads each line in the file. The loop ends when the last line has been read.

Comment: Lastly, you should consider adding the data to a “collection” like a `DataTable` or `List<T>` and then use that “collection” as a `DataSource` to the grid instead of adding the data directly into the grid. This will make life/coding easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

```
string csv = "John,Doe,21";
string[] split = csv.Split(',');

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn firstName = new 
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn lastName = new 
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn age = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(firstName);
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(lastName);
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(age);

dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[]{split[0],split[1],split[2]});
```

Comment: Thanks @Orlando Aguilera. But this code only works for one line... I have at least 10 lines that are divided into three columns.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers posted... i got some ideas e concluded a way to do it.

With just a little ajustement... it looked like this:

```
string csv = "text,text,text,text,text,text";
string[] split = csv.Split(',');

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn firstName = new 
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn lastName = new 
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn age = new 
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(firstName);
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(lastName);
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(age);

for (int i =0;i<strdata.Split(',').Length;i++) {
SettingsDGV.Rows.Add(new object[] { split[i], split[i+1], split[i+2] });
i++;i++;
 }
```

Comment: Your comment from the other answer… _”But this code only works for one line... I have at least 10 lines that are divided into three columns”_ … your example only has ONE line. Where are the 10 lines that are divided into three columns?